# Same values added to gridview for each row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I am using a RESTful web service and I have a list of all the object I am wanting to add to the gridview.  When I go to add them to each row in a DataTable, the results  are the same for each row. I am unsure what I am doing wrong?

```
protected void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Results trackResults = (Results)Session["Result"];
        foreach (Tracks t in trackResults.results)
        {

            //create datatable and columns,
             DataTable table = new DataTable();

            table.Columns.Add("Artist Name");
            table.Columns.Add("Collection Name");
            table.Columns.Add("Track Name");
            table.Columns.Add("Artwork");
            table.Columns.Add("Track Price");
            table.Columns.Add("Release Date");
            table.Columns.Add("Genre");



            for (int i = 0; i < trackResults.results.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr1 = table.NewRow();
                dr1["Artist Name"] = t.artistName;
                dr1["Collection Name"] = t.collectionName;
                dr1["Track Name"] = t.trackName;
                dr1["Artwork"] = t.artworkUrl30;
                dr1["Track Price"] = t.trackPrice;
                dr1["Release Date"] = t.releaseDate;
                dr1["Genre"] = t.primaryGenreName;
                table.Rows.Add(dr1);

            }
            GridView1.DataSource = table;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: where is foreach loop ending ?

put a } before "GridView1.DataSource = table;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to change the way you initialize things. Right now you are creating new table object for each record in `trackResults.results` and then on bind grid on each iteration as well. You might want to change it to this:

```
protected void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Results trackResults = (Results)Session["Result"];

    //create datatable and columns,
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Artist Name");
    table.Columns.Add("Collection Name");
    table.Columns.Add("Track Name");
    table.Columns.Add("Artwork");
    table.Columns.Add("Track Price");
    table.Columns.Add("Release Date");
    table.Columns.Add("Genre");

    foreach (Tracks t in trackResults.results)
    {
        DataRow dr1 = table.NewRow();
        dr1["Artist Name"] = t.artistName;
        dr1["Collection Name"] = t.collectionName;
        dr1["Track Name"] = t.trackName;
        dr1["Artwork"] = t.artworkUrl30;
        dr1["Track Price"] = t.trackPrice;
        dr1["Release Date"] = t.releaseDate;
        dr1["Genre"] = t.primaryGenreName;
        table.Rows.Add(dr1);
    }

    GridView1.DataSource = table;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: @user3487108- but you have accepted the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

1- There is no need to create datatable in foreach loop, and there is no need to write for loop.

2- You should create Data Table and columns outside loop and then create rows and add rows to table,

3- Assign table to datagridview where foreach loop ends.

i have edited your code below but didnt compile. Try it

```
protected void ButtonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Results trackResults = (Results)Session["Result"];

    //create datatable and columns,
         DataTable table = new DataTable();

        table.Columns.Add("Artist Name");
        table.Columns.Add("Collection Name");
        table.Columns.Add("Track Name");
        table.Columns.Add("Artwork");
        table.Columns.Add("Track Price");
        table.Columns.Add("Release Date");
        table.Columns.Add("Genre");

    foreach (Tracks t in trackResults.results)
    {

            DataRow dr1 = table.NewRow();
            dr1["Artist Name"] = t.artistName;
            dr1["Collection Name"] = t.collectionName;
            dr1["Track Name"] = t.trackName;
            dr1["Artwork"] = t.artworkUrl30;
            dr1["Track Price"] = t.trackPrice;
            dr1["Release Date"] = t.releaseDate;
            dr1["Genre"] = t.primaryGenreName;
            table.Rows.Add(dr1);

        }
        GridView1.DataSource = table;
        GridView1.DataBind();
}
```